# What are the benefits of signing a contract?

Tags: star-conflict

In Star Conflict, you can sign a contract with a faction.

The UI does not describe what exactly the benefits are. Also, it gives you a warning that it terminates all current contracts, even though I am only a member of the Empire.

So the questions related to this are:

- Is a contract additionally to the membership in one of the 3 main factions?
- What benefits do I gain from signing a contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contracts with a faction will allow you to take missions for this faction. By completing these missions, you will accrue reputation, which will eventually unlock some very nice equipment depending on your rank.

Take a look around the shop, in every buyable category, you will find items that mention "you need to be Rank X with faction Y to buy this". This is what signing a contract is about.

You can sign a contract with any faction, independently of your main allegiance. You can also revoke a contract to sign with another faction at any time, but will have to pay a fine depending on your rank with your current contractual faction.